# using MAKEFILE to copy files before compilation and delete them after

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to copy files befoe compilation (I have two source files with same name so I copy the files to a files with a different name) and delete them at the end of the MAKEFILE.
I am trying to do the folliwng but probably there is mismatch in the execution order. 
How can I do it correctly?

```
all: copy_dup_files $(dst_dir) $(APP_TARGET_LIB) delete_dup_files

copy_dup_files:  
    @echo "COPYING DUP FILES"
    $(shell cp /aaa/hmac.c /aaa/hmac1.c )
    $(shell cp /bbb/hmac.c /bbb/hmac2.c )

delete_dup_files:
    @echo "DELETING DUP FILES"
    $(shell rm /aaa/hmac1.c )
    $(shell rm /bbb/hmac2.c )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `$(shell)` is to produce an output which Make reads. The recipe lines should not have this construct at all.

```
# this is evaluated when the Makefile is read
value := $(shell echo "Use the shell to produce a value for a variable")

# this is evaluated when you say "make foo"
foo:
    echo 'No $$(shell ...) stuff here'
```

So, all the `$(shell ...)` stuff in your attempt gets evaluated when the `Makefile` is read, but before any actual target is executed.

Comment: As an aside, copying files before compiling seems like an antipattern in its own right.  Why are you doing that, what are you *actually* trying to accomplish ...?

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile is trying to say `/aaa/hmac1.c` depends on `/aaa/hmac.c`.
Thus we have:

```
/aaa/hmac1.c: /aaa/hmac.c
    cp $< $@

/bbb/hmac2.c: /bbb/hmac.c
    cp $< $@

/aaa/hmac1.o /bbb/hmac2.o: %.o: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@

myprog: /aaa/hmac1.o /bbb/hmac2.o
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

This is clean and parallel safe (a good test of any makefile).

There are innumerable style improvements you could make, like

- Get rid of the absolute paths
- Use symbolic links instead of copying
- Automatic dependency generation (for `.h` files, etc.)
- Don't besmirch the source tree — put all the intermediate files (the `.o`s and the temporary `.c`s) in their own build folder

&c. &c.

Comment: I need also to delete hmac1.c & hmac2.c at the end. How this can be done?

Comment: @RanTeshuva Personally I would leave them around. Think of them in the same way that you think about the `.o` files. Since they are build products, I would create them in the same temporary folders that the object files go in.

Comment: @RanTeshuva If you really want to delete them, then create and delete them in the recipe for compiling. Having a heavyweight `copy_dup_files` step that does all the copying in one go is a mis-step. _Make_ prefers fine grained dependencies (which then work well in parallel builds).